# Continuously slide in owl carousel, without delay stop and should immediate stop on hover

Tags: javascript, plugins, jquery-plugins, owl-carousel

Hii i am trying to slide continuous using owl carousel without delay in single slide and slide should stop immediate on hover.. Can anyone Please Help me out..

Answer (score 1):

check the documentation [owl-carosuel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#customizing) you just need to use *stopOnHover*

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
      stopOnHover: true,
      items : 4,
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add stopOnHover option to true to your js file. As per the documentation of owl carosuel, if we want to stop slide when we hover over It we can set stopOnHover: true;
and for smooth sliding of the slides you have to use autoplayTimeout option, which help us to set time in ms. So your code should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplayTimeout: 2000, // 2 sec you can change it as per you choice.(time between tow slide changes).
  stopOnHover: true, // To stop sliding on hover.
  responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1
           },
        600: {
            items: 2
           },
        1190: {
            items: 3
            }
           }             
 });
});
```